# Material UI options, getting back the value of the option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, console.log

stupid question, when I console.log target I get the following

```
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" id="mui-21183-option-0" data-option-index="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false" class="MuiAutocomplete-option" data-focus="true">Latvia</li>
```

How may I console log `Latvia` Instead, looking for the name itself.

Here is my code for the autocomplete options

```
<Autocomplete
    options={countries}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
    onChange={(e) => {
        console.log(e.target)
    }}
    renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
            {...params}
            variant="outlined"
            defaultValue={props.filledData.officeCountry}
            value={officeCountry || ""}
            label="REGISTERED OFFICE COUNTRY" />
    )}
/>
```

Comment: With or without any Javascript framework in use, `e.target` will return you an element (if there's one). What you want here is a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use `onInputChange` instead of `onChange`

It could look like this

```
 onInputChange={(e, value) => console.log(value)}
```

and the definition

```
onInputChange: (event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, value: string, reason: AutocompleteInputChangeReason)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onChange` prop gives you the selected option as second parameter in the callback.

The material-ui docs says:

> `onChange: Callback fired when the value changes.`

Signature:

```
function(event: object, value: T | T[], reason: string) => void
```

`event`: The event source of the callback.

`value`: The new value of the component.

`reason`: One of "create-option", "select-option", "remove-option", "blur" or "clear".

**So the solution is:**

```
 onChange={(e, selectedOption) => {
      console.log("OPTION -->", selectedOption); // {label: 'LTV', value: 'Latvia'}
      console.log("VALUE -->", selectedOption.value); // Latvia
 }}
```

[I'll live you a CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-project-vtx8v?file=/src/App.js)